# Azure DevTest lab VM artifacts

Tags: azure, artifact, azure-vm-role, azure-devtest-labs

I have created a lab VM and have tried to apply some custom artifacts. But I have seen that out of the 3 artifacts, one of them has failed (1st screenshot below). How do I rerun the failed artifact for the VM from the portal? I tried using the 'Apply artifacts' button to reinitiate the failed artifacts, but it seems to be creating another duplicate entry in the artifacts view for the VM (2nd screenshot). Does this mean that if this were to be made into a formula to spin further VMs, it would try to execute the same artifact twice? Thanks in advance for all the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try it and let us know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying artifacts after the VM is provisioned does not re-run the artifacts defined in the base. The base's artifacts are only executed at VM provisioning time, if some of the artifacts fails, you need to update your base (and create a new VM) to fix the issue or, **apply artifacts**.

Apply artifacts is a manual and one-time process that does NOT have to do with the base, but just for that specific VM.

You need to open the failed artifacts to get clues of the issue.

I had several issues and disposed several VMs until I get a correct order/process.